# Smooth UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, core-graphics, interpolation, uibezierpath, swift-playground

I created in a playground a uibezierpath added manually values and it works fine. The results is : 
[image]

Now my goal is to smooth the curve and remove these "sharp" corners. I'm thinking on a interpolation function but not sure. Below my actual code :

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics
import QuartzCore

class DemoView: UIView {


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let origin = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
        let radius = frame.size.width / 2

//        self.createCircle(origin: origin, radius: radius)
        self.addLinesInCircle(origin: origin, radius: radius)
    }

    func createCircle(origin: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArc(withCenter: origin, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi), clockwise: true)
        path.close()
        UIColor.clear.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

    func addLinesInCircle(origin: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        let bezier = UIBezierPath()

        let incrementAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat.pi / 24
        let ratios: [CGFloat] = [3/6, 5/6, 3/6, 1/6, 5/6, 2/6, 4/6, 2/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6,
                                 3/6, 5/6, 3/6, 1/6, 5/6, 2/6, 4/6, 2/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6,
                                 3/6, 5/6, 3/6, 1/6, 5/6, 2/6, 4/6, 2/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6,
                                 3/6, 5/6, 3/6, 1/6, 5/6, 2/6, 4/6, 2/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6, 4/6]

        for (index, ratio) in ratios.enumerated() {
            let point = CGPoint(x: origin.x + cos(CGFloat(index) * incrementAngle) * radius * ratio,
                                y: origin.y + sin(CGFloat(index) * incrementAngle) * radius * ratio)
            if index == 0 {
                bezier.move(to: point)
            } else {
                bezier.addLine(to: point)
            }
        }

        bezier.close()


        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor,UIColor.yellow.cgColor ,UIColor.black.cgColor] as CFArray, locations: nil)!

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
             ctx.saveGState()

        // Clip to the path
        bezier.addClip()
        // Draw the gradient in the clipped region
        ctx.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height), options: [])

        ctx.restoreGState()

    }

}

let demoView = DemoView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000))
```

If anyone has an idea or just keys words in order to look in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your help. I hope my explanations are enough...

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit further on "smooth the curve and remove these `sharp` corners"?

Comment: One image is better : https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/images/examples_qmlpolarchart1.png

Comment: You might be better off using `addArc` for that purpose instead of `addLine`. Or at the very least, look into `addCurve` & `addQuadCurve`

Comment: For people interested : https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/28/ios-interpolating-points/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interpolation using quadratic curve is like below:

```
    func
    MidPoint( _ l: CGPoint, _ r: CGPoint ) -> CGPoint { return CGPoint( x: ( l.x + r.x ) / 2, y: ( l.y + r.y ) / 2 ) }
    var start = CGPoint( x: 0, y: 0 )
    var prev = CGPoint( x: 0, y: 0 )
    for (index, ratio) in ratios.enumerated() {
        let point = CGPoint(x: origin.x + cos(CGFloat(index) * incrementAngle) * radius * ratio,
                            y: origin.y + sin(CGFloat(index) * incrementAngle) * radius * ratio)
        switch index {
        case  0:
            start = point
        case  1:
            bezier.move( to: MidPoint( start, point ) )
            prev = point
        default:
            bezier.addQuadCurve( to: MidPoint( prev, point ), controlPoint: prev )
            prev = point
        }
    }
    bezier.addQuadCurve( to: MidPoint( prev, start ), controlPoint: prev )
```

[image]