# How to make UIBezierPath smooth in Swift

Tags: swift, charts, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a line chart which represents a set of values (x and y) in a smooth bezier curve. This works fine, except when the x-values are close to each other and the y-values go from a continuous line to a lower or higher value. The values are not shown in the chart itself, but here is an image illustrating my problem:

[image: Chart Issue]

As you can see, the line makes a backwards movement before continuing to the next point. I would like this to not happen and smoothen out. To generate the data points, I use [this library from Minh Nguyen](https://medium.com/@leonardnguyen/building-your-own-chart-in-ios-part-2-line-chart-7b5cfc7c866), which has helped me a lot. The only problem is this issue still. For easiness, here is the code I currently use:

```
private func controlPointsFrom(points: [CGPoint]) -> [CurvedSegment] {
    var result: [CurvedSegment] = []
    let delta: CGFloat = 0.3
    for i in 1..<points.count {
        let A = points[i-1]
        let B = points[i]
        let controlPoint1 = CGPoint(x: A.x + delta*(B.x-A.x), y: A.y + delta*(B.y - A.y))
        let controlPoint2 = CGPoint(x: B.x - delta*(B.x-A.x), y: B.y - delta*(B.y - A.y))
        let curvedSegment = CurvedSegment(controlPoint1: controlPoint1, controlPoint2: controlPoint2)
        result.append(curvedSegment)
    }

    for i in 1..<points.count-1 {
        let M = result[i-1].controlPoint2
        let N = result[i].controlPoint1
        let A = points[i]
        let MM = CGPoint(x: 2 * A.x - M.x, y: 2 * A.y - M.y)
        let NN = CGPoint(x: 2 * A.x - N.x, y: 2 * A.y - N.y)
        result[i].controlPoint1 = CGPoint(x: (MM.x + N.x)/2, y: (MM.y + N.y)/2)
        result[i-1].controlPoint2 = CGPoint(x: (NN.x + M.x)/2, y: (NN.y + M.y)/2)
    }
    return result
}

func createCurvedPath(_ dataPoints: [CGPoint]) -> UIBezierPath? {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: dataPoints[0])
    var curveSegments: [CurvedSegment] = []
    let useDataPoints = dataPoints.filter { ($0.y < 1000) }
    curveSegments = controlPointsFrom(points: useDataPoints)
    for i in 1..<useDataPoints.count {
        path.addCurve(to: useDataPoints[i], controlPoint1: curveSegments[i - 1].controlPoint1, controlPoint2: curveSegments[i - 1].controlPoint2)
    }
    return path
}
```

For documentation, I would refer to the tutorial/blogpost [I linked earlier](https://medium.com/@leonardnguyen/building-your-own-chart-in-ios-part-2-line-chart-7b5cfc7c866). I figure the issue should be somewhere in the calculation of `controlPoint1` and `controlPoint2` in the `controlPointsFrom` function. When I remove the delta or make it 0, it just become straight lines but then the issue doesn't occur either. So the math should be different I think, to keep track of the previous value and perhaps don't create a control point with a higher or lower y-value when the next point is lower or higher, respectively. But I am unable to figure out how to make it work. Any smart mind who can make this happen?

Would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 1):

try this:
[Smooth UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812180/smooth-uibezierpath)

https://medium.com/@ramshandilya/draw-smooth-curves-through-a-set-of-points-in-ios-34f6d73c8f9

Comment: Have been looking into this indeed. Great reference, but I'm not able to make it work in my current project. When I try and replace and edit my code following the link above, it messes up my chart completely. Any suggestion how to implement it into the code I provided or what I should change to my existing code to make it work?