# Drawing perfect rounding lines, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I'm working on a drawing app prototype and what I want to achieve is perfect rounding lines. I've implemented drawing via curves but still, my lines look a little bit pixelated.

Here is my result:

[image]

and here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        private var currentPoint: CGPoint?
        private var previousPoint1: CGPoint?
        private var previousPoint2: CGPoint?
        private var lineColor = UIColor.black
        private var lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
        private var lineAlpha = CGFloat(1)
        @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
            
            previousPoint1 = touch.previousLocation(in: self.view)
            currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        }
    
        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
            
            previousPoint2 = previousPoint1
            previousPoint1 = touch.previousLocation(in: self.view)
            currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
            
            let mid1 = middlePoint(previousPoint1!, previousPoint2: previousPoint2!)
            let mid2 = middlePoint(currentPoint!, previousPoint2: previousPoint1!)
            
            draw(move: CGPoint(x: mid1.x, y: mid1.y), to: CGPoint(x: mid2.x, y: mid2.y), control: CGPoint(x: previousPoint1!.x, y: previousPoint1!.y))
        }
    
        public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        }
    
        private func middlePoint(_ previousPoint1: CGPoint, previousPoint2: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
            return CGPoint(x: (previousPoint1.x + previousPoint2.x) * 0.5, y: (previousPoint1.y + previousPoint2.y) * 0.5)
        }
    
        func draw(move: CGPoint, to: CGPoint, control: CGPoint) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
            guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
            imageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds)
            ctx.move(to: move)
            ctx.addQuadCurve(to: to, control: control)
            ctx.setLineCap(.round)
            ctx.setLineJoin(.round)
            ctx.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
            ctx.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)
            ctx.setBlendMode(.normal)
            ctx.setAlpha(lineAlpha)
            ctx.strokePath()
            let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            imageView.image = finalImage
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
    }
```

P.S. I want to draw via context, not using `drawRect`

Comment: You need to implement some better Bezier path smoothing in order to get the result you want, this answer should provide you with a decent reference for smoothing via interpolation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812180/smooth-uibezierpath

Comment: @Adis Can you please show me how to do it in my example?

Comment: This (article)[https://medium.com/@ramshandilya/draw-smooth-curves-through-a-set-of-points-in-ios-34f6d73c8f9] cen be useful as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the scale of imageContext you are creating is not correct. Rather than creating your context with **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext** try to create it with **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions** and give scale value as 0. When you specify a scale value of 0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen. Updated code snippet would be like the one follows.

```
func draw(move: CGPoint, to: CGPoint, control: CGPoint) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0)
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        imageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds)
        ctx.move(to: move)
        ctx.addQuadCurve(to: to, control: control)
        ctx.setLineCap(.round)
        ctx.setLineJoin(.round)
        ctx.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        ctx.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)
        ctx.setBlendMode(.normal)
        ctx.setAlpha(lineAlpha)
        ctx.strokePath()
        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        imageView.image = finalImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem, but now UI lagging a little bit, do you know solution for this?

Comment: You should try having a customview and draw paths into it rather than creating images for every event.